# Issues in R with the syntax

Tags: r, syntax-error

My data set say data123 has columns Order.No,date,transactions, etc. I am doing a pivot using sqldf for which below is the code

```r
Pivot123=sqldf("Select Order.No,Date,Month,Year,Category from data123")
```

When running this function, I am getting the below error

```
Error: near "Order": syntax error
```

What is the reason? I rechecked but the column name is correct
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Table.ColumnName` convention is biting you here. Since I'm inferring that `Order.No` is a column name, then change your question to one of:

```r
sqldf("Select [Order.No],Date,Month,Year,Category from data123")
sqldf('Select "Order.No",Date,Month,Year,Category from data123') # note the shift from ' to "
```

The premise is that you're telling the SQL engine that `Order.No` is an *identifier* (complete name), not to be separated by the normal dot-notation format. There are two common ways to quote identifiers: `[Order.No]` and `"Order.No"`. The single-quote method only identifies string literals, so `'Order.No'` does not work (try it and see).

A good example uses a common technique: assign a (typically shorter) alias, especially useful when table names are long:

```r
#         the alias is used here
#             vvv.            vvv.      vvv.       vvv.      vvv.
sqldf("Select tb1.[Order.No], tb1.Date, tb1.Month, tb1.Year, tb1.Category
       from data123 tb1")
#                   ^^^ this is the alias
```

This is not always necessary, but a time when it *is* necessary is when you are querying from multiple tables and they share column names.

Lastly, you can opt to "quote" all column names, it does no harm:

```r
sqldf("Select [Order.No], [Date], [Month], [Year], [Category] from data123")
```

Comment: Also is the above function that I used a kind of pivot or should I use some other function?

Comment: Pivoting is possible in SQL, but perhaps not as straight-forward as R's `tidyr::pivot_*` or `data.table::melt`/`::dcast`.